# index.html not found while deploying MERN app to render.com

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, mern, render.com

I was trying to deploy my MERN based E-commerce website on render.com, after the render terminal shows the build was successful the the webpage shows the error as,

**{“message”:“ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ‘/opt/render/project/src/frontend/build/index.html’”,“stack”:null}**

I’m a complete beginner to render and MERN too,

- I have no bulid folder in my local
- then I tried to create another test app by **npx create-react-app test** to check if build folder is actually present in there or not, But it is not there, I’m totally in Confused now…

I’m Giving my repo here → [stunning spark](https://github.com/Dev-jr-8/stunning-sprak)

I just want to have clear answers for my questions(Please!!!)

- Things I want to change in my directory to deploy and host my app Successfully.
- Things Need to be configured in the render’s settings

Thanks in Advance!!!

I just want to deploy and host my application on render.com

Answer (score 1):

Just run `npm run build` into your frontend folder and do check you have removed the "build" keyword from the `.gitignore` file because it won't let you push the build folder to GitHub and you are good to go.